# How to add SixLabor.ImageSharp in .net core project

Tags: .net-core, imagesharp

Hey I want to resize images stored in a folder using .net core 3.1.  The library I am trying to use is SixLabor.ImageSharp. I tried to install its latest version using nuget package manager and it was successfully installed and later on I added namespace SixLabor.Imagesharp in my .Cs file. but I am getting an error Namespace sixlabor.imagesharp not found. how can i use image sharp in my project. I read its documentation it was mentioned that Image sharp is available in Nuget package manager but its not working for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version of .net are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install the Nuget Package "SixLabor.ImageSharp" in the desired project. Once done, in your Startup.cs configure it as mentioned on their getting started page https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp.web/gettingstarted.html